# Oracle SQL paste column into variable

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

In advance I am just starting out in Oracle SQL so please bear with me.
So I want to paste a column from my table into a variable, the issue is that I have to adjust my variable by adding a "," after every single entry.
Below is my attempt in achieving just that.

```
DECLARE
    email clob;
    counter int;
    set counter := 0;

BEGIN
    WHILE counter < 500
    LOOP
        SELECT mail INTO email FROM spam 
        email += ","
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Email : ' || email )
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Counter : ' || counter )
        SET @counter  = @counter  + 1
    END LOOP   
END
```

Comment: That code is far from being valid PL/SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, looks like you want to concatenate email addresses. Is that so? If YES, then:

```
DECLARE
  email  VARCHAR2(32000);
BEGIN
  FOR cur_r IN (SELECT mail 
                FROM spam
                WHERE ROWNUM < 500
               )
  LOOP
    email := email ||','|| cur_r.mail;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(cur_r.mail);
  END LOOP;

  email := RTRIM(email, ',');    
END;
```

- instead of counter, use `ROWNUM`
- you can't really expect to display the whole string (i.e. the final `email` value) as its length is limited to 255 characters

---

Alternatively, if you don't expect the result string to be longer than 4000 characters, you could use `LISTAGG`:

```
DECLARE
  email  VARCHAR2(32000);
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG(mail, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY mail)
  INTO email
  FROM spam
  WHERE ROWNUM < 500;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I was indeed trying to concatenate the adresses.